# Thread closing on phone sleep

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

I am having trouble with my game thread that closes when the device goes to sleep or the power button is pressed (thus switching off the screen) ... when the screen is switched back on, the thread does not respond (I presume because it has closed) ...

Any thoughts on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not avoid it, its a natural android reflex to save Battery. Assuming you know the android lifecycle, naturally you have to store your info in onPause() or onStop() methods when sleep mode occurs , and then retrieve them in onResume() when the screen is turned back on.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3061985/4600745)

Essentially; Stop your thread when phone leaves your program. Restart your thread when and if returning to the application.

Comment: Without knowing any of your code you can set a flag in your thread. Change the flag value in your `onPause` and `onResume` and handle whatever you need in your thread. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11408626/4600745) for an example.