# run thread make the app crash in android

Tags: android, json, multithreading

I created the thread to bring the json data from the web site, then I analyse the data and show the notification .

But when I close the app the thread is still working after open the app again the app crashes. any solution ? and also i was using the *interrupt()* in the **onDestroy** Life cycle

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    //condition = 1;
    test.interrupt();
    //test.destroy();

}
```

Comment: What does the stack trace say? If you try to touch UI of already destroyed Activity it will crash. How do you handle interrupt? I think you don't have any sleep in your thread so interrupt will not work for you. Try to use AsyncTask or IntentService+Broadcast to do async stuff.

Comment: W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c0da0) thats the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your run() method you'd need to periodically check the status of `ThreadName.interrupted()`

There is a good tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 1):

`onDestroy()` method will be called by JVM so if you close the app `onDestroy()` call is not guaranteed. Try moving the code from `onDestroy()` to `onStop()` method and `onStop()` will get called when you close the app.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use AsynTask do the Rest Call.
Reference: [Dev Forum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

If you are hard press on using the thread then try calling it in onPause() where we can do some heavy lifting in comparison to other overridden methods.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
      super.onPause();
      test.interrupt();
}
```

Reference: [How to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055211/android-thread-management-onpause)

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that the interrupt function really called, because put interupt in onDestroy() is never a guarantee will be called. try put it in **onStop()**

or using asynctask to get json data